# Why does '-' or space between subgroups of digits in regular expression fail?

Tags: regex

I am looking at different number schemes of different types of credit card.
For example:
    Discover: `\b6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}\b`
    VISA: `\b4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})\b`
    Diners Club: `\b3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11} \b`

Some people like to put '-' or space between subgroups of digits when writing the credit card number, and the above REs fail to capture them.
For example: `(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b`

Why is it happen?

Comment: Those regular expressions don't match spaces or hyphens because they don't attempt to match spaces or hyphens.  Are you asking how to rewrite them so that they would match spaces or hyphens?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to match spaces and hyphens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just explicitly ask for the spaces/hyphens between subgroups. You haven't mentioned them in your original regexes. For example, for the Discover pattern, you gave this:

```
6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}
```

I've left out the `\b` for brevity. Unless I'm missing something you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`:

```
6(?:011|5\d{2})\d{12}
```

Split the latter 12 digits into three groups of four:

```
6(?:011|5\d{2})\d{4}\d{4}\d{4}
```

Then put spaces/hyphen between:

```
6(?:011|5\d{2})[ -]*\d{4}[ -]*\d{4}[ -]*\d{4}
```

which can be expressed without duplication like so:

```
6(?:011|5\d{2})(?:[ -]*\d{4}){3}
```

Similar strategies can be applied to the others.